# Counting Tic-Tac-Toe draws on larger grids

Tags: mathematics, logical-deduction, combinatorics, board-games

Alice and Bob play a game of Tic-Tac-Toe on a grid of size $N \times M$. The rules of this game are the same as the original Tic-Tac-Toe:

- Alice plays first (white); Bob plays second (black).
- On each player's turn, they put a piece of their own on an empty cell on the grid.
- When a player's pieces form a three-in-a-row (horizontally, vertically, or diagonally in either 45-degree direction), the player wins.
- If no one wins until the entire board is filled up with pieces, the game ends in a draw.

Instead of trying to win, Alice and Bob decided to cooperate towards a draw. How many distinct drawn endgames are possible when $N, M \ge 4$? Two endgames are distinct if the pieces on at least one cell is different. The order in which each piece is placed is not considered.

For example, $3 \times 3$ grid has 16 distinct drawn endgames:

[image]

When one side of the grid is 3, the answer is given as [OEIS A339631](https://oeis.org/A339631).

Comment: Is there an elegant solution, or is this basically a computer programming assignment?

Comment: @KrisVanBael This can be solved without programming, unlike when $N=3$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer is

> 18 if M=N=4, 14 if M=4 or N=4 but not both  EDIT *8 if M,N>4 and their product is divisible by 4. 4 if M,N both odd and 6 otherwise.*

Reasoning:

> There can  be no 2x2 square of one colour because any containing 3x3 would have to fill all other squares with the other colour which would then win.
>
> ```
>     o o .             o o x
>     o o .   forces    o o x
>     . . .             x x x
> ```

> 2x2 squares with three pieces of one colour can only appear at the corners because
>
> ```
>     o o .             o o x
>     o x .   forces    o x .
>     . . .             x . .
> ```
>
> ```
>     o o . .             o o x .
>     x o . .   forces    x o o .
>     . . . .             . x x x
> ```
>
> ```
>     x o . .             x o x o
>     o o . .   forces    o o x x
>     . . . .             x x o o
>     . . . .             o . . x
> ```

> up to symmetry w.r.t. the diagonal.
>  Such corner pieces can only happen on 4xN or Mx4 boards and can only occur in pairs.

> If M,N>4 therefore every 2x2-square must be balanced and there are only 8 viable 3x3 squares namely the rotations and complement of
>
> ```
>     o o x
>     x x o
>     o o x
> ```

> As any sub 3x3 square determines all others (via unique 3x2 or 2x3 overlap with shifted-by-1 locations) 8 is also EDIT: *an upper bound for* the overall number of solutions. The solutions can be thought of as cuttings from rectangles made entirely from

> ```
>     x o
>     x o
>     o x
>     o x
> ```

> or its transpose.
>  EDIT: *Of those all that are overall balanced or have Alice one up are reachable.*

> If N=4<M there are 6 additional solutions depending on whether the left end is unbalanced or the right end or both each option coming with its complement. if M=N=4, there are another 4 (top two unbalanced or bottom two unbalanced plus complements)

Comment: Your answer for N or M = 4 is correct, but the others is not. Hint: Alice and Bob take turns. (Sorry if it's not clear enough in the OP) Also I have to admit that the remaining part may be a bit tedious.

Comment: @Bubbler Oops. I hope it is fixed now.